# Check for CompareIgnoreCase in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, case-sensitive

I am a c++ developer and recently shifted to C#. I am developing a WPF application where I need to check for the CASE Sensitive. I had done this in c++ as follows:

```
// BoardName and Board Version are of tye String
if(m_boardName->compareIgnoreCase("S1010012") == 0)
{   
    m_voltageChannels = redhookChannels;
}
else if(m_boardName->compareIgnoreCase("S1010018") == 0)//For bavaria board
{
    if(m_boardVersion->compareIgnoreCase("001A") == 0 || 
       m_boardVersion->compareIgnoreCase("001B") == 0 || 
       m_boardVersion->compareIgnoreCase("001C") == 0 )
    {
        m_voltageChannels = bavaria1Channels;
    }
    else if(m_boardVersion->compareIgnoreCase("002B") == 0)
    {
        m_voltageChannels = bavaria2Channel;
    }   
}
```

In my WPF application, I did this:

```
string redhookboardname = "S1010012";
    string redhookboardnameCase = "s1010012";

    string bavariaboardnameCase = "s1010018";
    string bavaria1boardversion1Case = "001a";
    string bavaria1boardversion2Case = "001b";
    string bavaria1boardversion3Case = "001c";

    string bavariaboardname = "S1010018";
    string bavaria1boardversion1 = "001A";
    string bavaria1boardversion2 = "001B";
    string bavaria1boardversion3 = "001C";

    string bavaria2boardversion = "002B";
    string bavaria2boardversionCase = "002b";

    public void OnChannel()
    {
        if (redhookboardnameCase.Equals(redhookboardname, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            mVoltageStruct = redhookboard;
        }

        else if (bavariaboardnameCase.Equals(bavaria1boardversion1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (bavaria1boardversion1Case.Equals(bavariaboardname, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || bavaria1boardversion2Case.Equals(bavaria1boardversion2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || bavaria1boardversion3Case.Equals(bavaria1boardversion3, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                mVoltageStruct = bavaria1board;
            }
            else if (bavaria2boardversionCase.Equals(bavaria2boardversion, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                mVoltageStruct = bavaria2board;
            }
        } 
    }
```

**[UPDATED CODE]**: Can this be achieved like I did above???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload for string.Equals

[String.Equals Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx)

For example:

```
string str1 = "s101001b";
string str2 = "S101001B";
if (str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //equal
}
```

You may also see one interesting article: [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx)

Comment: U mean: `string str1 = "s101001b";
string str2 = "S101001B";
if (str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //equal
}`

Comment: Yes, they will be equal in that case

Comment: @StonedJesus, you may be asked to Convert both string to a same case, and then compare e.g. `if(str1.ToLower() == str2.ToLower())` but before doing that you should read the article in the answer :)

Comment: `Equals` is definitely what you want here, but you can also get the same -1/0/1 result as `compareIgnoreCase` using `String.Compare(str1, str2, true)` if you need the sort order.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Yes you are right. I am just experimenting with it :) I used compareIgnorecase in my code. Is it corrent and does it yield the expected result as done in C++ code? :)

Comment: @StonedJesus Your existing C# doesn't give the same result as your C++ code if that's what you're asking, IndexOf could return 4 and you'd still consider it equal, while it could mean that 'S01' is in 4:th position of 'A332S01'. Your C++ does "equals" while your C# does "contains".

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: have a look at the updated code. Is it fine now?

Comment: @StonedJesus Looks good, although you may want to keep the old code too not to make the answers "out of date". Hard for anyone else with the same question to find it when the question is all changed around :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string.Compare

```
if(string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==0)
{
//equal
}
```